# php/html: Force line breaks to appear inside textarea

Tags: html, textarea, line-breaks

This should not be that hard but I can't seem to find information on it.  How do you get line breaks to appear inside a text area when you are echoing it from the server?  In other words what is `<some code>` in line below?

```
<text area>first line <some code> second line <some code> third line</text area>
```

I know how to write out `<some code>`.  I just need to know what it should be.  I have tried `\n, \r\n, '\n', "\n", \N` and variations but cannot get the line breaks to display.

Note: This is not about displaying in HTML so `<br>` is not what I want.  This is not about getting it to display if you are typing it yourself where you can type a carriage return, i.e. :

```
<textarea>first line
second line  </textarea>
```

When you are outputting from server you cannot use keyboard.  This is what code to accomplish above.

Thanks for any suggestions

Comment: Line breaks usually contains the "\n" for line-feed and "\r" for carriage return. Matching /n is not equal to \n.

Comment: I corrected question.\ is what I tried.

Answer (score 1):

This is a super old question, but I ran into the same issue ajaxing content into a text area.

Thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7981786/line-breaks-in-textarea-element) I used the html code for a new line, `&#10;` and that worked for me. So basically:

`<textarea> Here's my returned text &#10; And it gets two lines </textarea>`

which (at least for me) comes out as

> Here's my returned text
>
> And it gets two lines

Comment: I too had similar issue but mine was that the first line break of text area was being stripped automatically. Apparently this is a browser feature. I had to use &#013;&#010; together to get it to show up. http://haacked.com/archive/2008/11/18/new-line-quirk-with-html-textarea.aspx/

Answer (score 0):

try this

<'p'>firstline<'/p'>

<'p'>secondline<'/p'>

remove comma from p and /p

Answer (score 0):

for display \n in html you should use nl2br() php function .
otherwise you should using "\n" (not "/n") for break the line inside your text ;

Answer (score 0):

You should try \r\n instead of /r/n.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use "\r\n" (with double quotes) when echoing it out from PHP.