# html text box is not displaying carriage returns from the input area

Tags: html

I have this description box in or CRM page that displays text like this in the Description box.

**Description**

> System
>   Information------------------------------------------------------------------------------OS Windows 7 Home Premium x64 Edition 6.1 (build: 7600)BIOS Version
>   HPQOEM - 42302e31Last booted 6/4/2013 5:24 PMComputer Name
>   BRANDON-PCCPUInformation-----------------------------------------------------CPU
>   Name AMDCPU Clock 2712 MHzCPU Description Number 2 Level 16 Model 6
>   Stepping 2CPU Usage
>   74%---------------------------------------------------------Memory
>   Information-------------------------------Physical Memory Size 2.87 GB

The code for this text box is as follows.

```
<table><tr><td align="left">
    <?php echo $AppUI->_('Description');?>:
    <br />
    <textarea name="task_description" class="textarea" cols="60" rows="10" wrap="virtual"><?php echo @$obj->task_description;?></textarea>
    </td></tr></table><br />
```

The way that I type in is as follows:

> System Information
>   ------------------------------------------------------------------------------ OS       Windows 7 Home Premium x64 Edition 6.1 (build: 7600) BIOS
>   Version             HPQOEM - 42302e31 Last booted
>   6/4/2013 5:24 PM Computer Name            BRANDON-PCCPU Information
>   ----------------------------------------------------- CPU Name         AMD CPU Clock        2712 MHz CPU Description  Number 2 Level 16 Model
>   6 Stepping 2 CPU Usage        74%
>   --------------------------------------------------------- Memory Information
>   ------------------------------- Physical Memory Size    2.87 GB

When I go back in to edit it the input box is also messed up like it's displaying.  I have tried all the adding of the code from the following places but I can't get this to work.

1. [New line in text area](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8627902/new-line-in-text-area)
2. [Line breaks in textarea element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7981786/line-breaks-in-textarea-element)

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: When I copy and paste the piece of text above into a textarea, it works as expected, no suprise there. I'll bet the problem isn't in the code we see here. Perhaps it's in the php, don't know how to help you without more info/code. :(

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<?
$desc = str_replace("\n",PHP_EOL, @$obj->task_description);?>

<table>
    <tr>
        <td align="left">
           <?php echo $AppUI->_('Description');?>:
           <br />
          <textarea name="task_description" class="textarea" cols="60" rows="10" wrap="virtual">
           <?php echo $desc;?></textarea>
       </td>
     </tr>
</table><br />
```