# newline using shift + enter in javascript is not behaving as newline in php

Tags: javascript, php, newline, str-replace, nl2br

I have a textarea

```
 <textarea name="a" id="a" onkeyup="gh(event);" cols="30" rows="1"></textarea>
```

and im using it to transfer text into my server 
but just like facebook comment box there is no submit button data submits when user presses <kbd>Enter</kbd> and when users presses <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> they are allow to create to new line here is my JS Function

```
function yh(e) {
  if(e.keyCode)
  {
    unicode = e.keyCode;
  }
  else
  {
    unicode = e.charCode;
  }
  if (e.keyCode == 13 && e.shiftKey)
  {
    return false;
  }
  else if(e.keyCode == 13 )
  {
    //do submit 
  }
}
```

but when i submit the data and then fetch it then the new line doesnot appearing i have used `str_replace("\n","<br/>","$data")` and `nl2br($data)` function of PHP but they are not working can you tell me where is the problem??

Comment: Var dump your content and look for line breaks

Comment: Are you using any editor, such as tinymce, that would strip these out, or any other processes that would be removing the new line?

Comment: gh is being called onkeyup by the textarea but your function is named yh. Other than that, this may be similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7981786/line-breaks-in-textarea-element

Comment: i am using sublime 2 @jtlowe

Comment: Are you able to see the new lines in your database? Are you sure the text is making it to the database with new line characters? This might narrow down where the problem is.

Comment: @jtlowe no str_replace is not working so there is no <br/> in databases!